# Cannot install Edubuntu using USB

Tags: usb, startup, edubuntu

I want to install Edubuntu 13.04 using USB. I've gone through [this](http://edubuntu.org/documentation/12.04/installation-guide) guide but I still have a problem.

I'm running on Edubuntu 7.04, but I can't find **Startup Disk Creator** that the guide refers to. I don't have it and I can't download it. I found Startup Disk Creator on [this page](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/usb-creator-gtk/) but it can't be downloaded. Help.

I've also posted this issue in Edubuntu's website, facebook... etc. But, none answered me

Answer (score 0):

There are several programs out there that creates bootable USB disks. I usually recommend unetbootin, as it is friendlier to use (my opinion)

Unetbootin can be found in the official repositories:

Open terminal: Ctrl+Alt+t

```
sudo apt-get install unebootin
```

You should be able to install Startup Disk Creator the same way:

```
sudo apt-get install usb-creator-gtk
```

If this fails, please edit your question and add the error messages from the terminal.

Hope this helps!